Area of Triangle $∆DEF$ in a Regular Tetrahedron

QUESTION:
Given regular tetrahedron $ABCD$, points $E$, $F$ are on $AB$, $AC$, respectively, such that $BE =3$,$EF =4$,and $EF$ is parallel to plane $BCD$. Then the area of $ΔDEF$ is _____
My Work
I placed the vertices of the regular tetrahedron in $3D$ space. The coordinates I used for the vertices were based on the symmetry of the regular tetrahedron, with side length $s = 6$ for simplicity. The coordinates for vertices $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ were:

$A = (0, 0, 0)$

$B = (6, 0, 0)$

$C = \left( 3, 3\sqrt{3}, 0 \right)$

$D = \left( 3, \sqrt{3}, 4\sqrt{6} \right)$

Since $BE = 3$, I used the fact that $E$ divides $AB$ in the ratio $1:1$, meaning $E$ is the midpoint of $AB$. This gave the coordinates $E = (3, 0, 0)$.

To find $F$, I used the condition that $EF$ is parallel to the plane $BCD$. I computed the normal vector to the plane $BCD$ using the cross product of vectors $\mathbf{BD}$ and $\mathbf{BC}$. I then placed $F$ on edge $AC$ such that $EF = 4$ and $EF \parallel \text{plane } BCD$.

I calculated the vectors $\mathbf{DE}$ and $\mathbf{DF}$ using the coordinates of $D$, $E$, and $F$.

To find the area of $\Delta DEF$, I used the formula:
$\text{Area} = \frac{1}{2} \left| \mathbf{DE} \times \mathbf{DF} \right|$
I computed the cross product $\mathbf{DE} \times \mathbf{DF}$ and found its magnitude, which gave the area of $\Delta DEF$ as $19.23$ but in the answers the answer to this question is $2√33$ which is around $11.489$.
Can anyone please tell me where did I go wrong and also tell me the correct approach that will lead to the correct answer.



I think the problem is that you assumed side length s=6. That choice puts E at the midpoint of AB. Since EF is parallel to BC (this follows from the conditions though I'm not sure how to prove it nicely), looking at similar triangles ABC and AEF shows that EF is forced to be 3. Whatever calculations you did to get your F, they cannot satisfy all the conditions because you imposed the incorrect additional condition s=6.

Hint: $AB=7$. Do you see why?

The mistake you made was assuming side length to be $6$, but it is actually $7$. Here's how:
We can easily see that $\triangle AEF \sim \triangle ABC$
$\implies \dfrac{AE}{AB}=\dfrac{EF}{BC}$
$\implies \dfrac{s-3}{s}=\dfrac{4}{s} \implies \boxed{s=7}$ , where $s$ is side length of tetrahedron.
Now, we can easily compute the coordinates of the vertices and of other points, but coordinates of $D, E, F$ are required only.
$D=\left(\dfrac{7}{2},\dfrac{7\sqrt3}{6},\dfrac{7\sqrt6}{3}\right)$
$E=\left(4,0,0\right)$
$F=\left(2,2\sqrt3,0\right)$
Thus, $\mathbf{DE}=\dfrac{1}{2}\hat{i}-\dfrac{7\sqrt3}{6}\hat{j}-\dfrac{7\sqrt6}{3}\hat{k}$
and $\mathbf{DF}=-\dfrac{3}{2}\hat{i}+\dfrac{5\sqrt3}{6}\hat{j}-\dfrac{7\sqrt6}{3}\hat{k}$
Thus, Area of $\triangle DEF=\dfrac{1}{2}\left|\mathbf{DE} \times \mathbf{DF}\right|$
$\implies$ Area of triangle $DEF = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot| \begin{vmatrix}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
\dfrac{1}{2} & -\dfrac{7\sqrt{3}}{6} & -\dfrac{7\sqrt{6}}{3} \\
-\dfrac{3}{2} & \dfrac{5\sqrt{3}}{6} & -\dfrac{7\sqrt{6}}{3}
\end{vmatrix}|$
$=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left|\dfrac{14\sqrt{18}}{3}\hat{i}+\dfrac{14\sqrt6}{3}\hat{j}-\dfrac{4\sqrt3}{3}\hat{k}\right|$
$=\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{14\sqrt{18}}{3}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{14\sqrt6}{3}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{-4\sqrt3}{3}\right)^2}$
$=\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \sqrt{528}$
$=\boxed{2\sqrt{33}}$
$\approx 11.489$

Since $EF$ is parallel to the plane $BCD$, it doesn’t intersect any line in the plane $BCD$. In particular, $EF$ and $BC$ are non-intersecting lines in the plane $ABC$, which makes them parallel. So triangles $ABC$ and $AEF$ are similar, which means $AEF$ is an equilateral triangle. Then $EF=4$ implies $AE=AF=4$, which further implies $AB=7$.
One can choose the coordinates of all the points to be
$$
A=(0,0,0),\quad B=(r,r,0),\quad C=(r,0,r),\quad D=(0,r,r),\quad E=(t,t,0),\quad F=(t,0,t),
$$
where $r=7/\sqrt2$ and $t=4/\sqrt2$. Now the area of triangle $DEF$ is
$$
\triangle DEF = \frac12\Vert \mathbf{DE} \times \mathbf{DF}\Vert = \frac12 \Vert ((t-r)^2-r^2,-t^2,-t^2)\Vert = \frac14 \Vert (-40,-16,-16)\Vert = 2\sqrt{33}.
$$
